# less command option % is not working - no such file or directory

Tags: command-line, less

I successfully opened a file with `less` command. Then I typed `!` for shell command. In the shell I typed `du -h %`. `%` is supposed to be the file name to the shell. However it is not working. Shell replies `no such file and directory`. Am I missing something??

Comment: in your example `%` is a file (or directory), so you asked for the disk-usage (in human format) for file/directory named %.   Do you have a file or directory named % ??  ( where % is your filename, and does not represent anything other than the name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> after `!` and you were returned to the shell where `%` does not have any special meaning.

Instead, of pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, type

```
! du -h %
```

inside `less` and it should return the size of the file in the shell

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. less is a great tool. BTW do you know what the meaning of the phrase "less is more"?? They say it is a bit of hacker humor. I don't get it.

Comment: @Smile there is a file reading application called `more`, which came before `less` and has fewer features. In (British?) English there is a common saying "less is more" which means something like "in this situation doing or having a little of something is more effective or aesthetic than doing or having a lot", or "less is better than more [in the present case]" since `less` is better than `more` (is has more features) the phrase applies but with its underlying literal meaning reversed (yeah explaining jokes does not make them funny)...

Comment: Your reply is the best reply ever in my English language life. I understand the meaning now and I can feel it. If the phrase were written my language and you asked me, I would probably not reply well. Your reply totally rocks. Thanks Zanna.